# Reload search glitch

Tags: php, html, search

http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test%20search/searchbeta.html (Try looking up google for example) For some reason when i start typing then click enter the page reloads. I have no idea why? Is there something wrong with my code? I cant really find it. Also you might want to check the code of the page i gave you earlier. If you can also find out why it opens a page in another tab and fix it that would be very helpful too thanks :)

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0)
{
$hint="";
for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
  {
  $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
  if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
    {
    //find a link matching the search text
    if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
      {
      if ($hint=="")
        {
        $hint="<a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      else
        {
        $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
        $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
        "' target='_blank'>" . 
        $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Set output to "No suggestions" if no hint were found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="")
  {
  $response="No suggestion";
  }
else
  {
  $response=$hint;
  }

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent default event for the "form" html element in your searchbeta.html page.
This is what I cat suggest to you in js with using jQuery lib:

```
$(function(){
   $("form").on("submit",function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

Don't forget connect jQuery lib to your page

Comment: Am i supposed to put that code into the page or in the php?

Comment: I put the code as a script in the http://onlythebestoftheweb.x10.mx/test%20search/searchbeta.html page but it didnt do anything.

Comment: connect jQuery lib. See my example on jsbin

Comment: You might want to check my pages code but i think i did it correctly. It doesnt seem like it changed anything...

Comment: Never mind fixed! Thanks! Also do you know anything about how to stop if from opening a new tab with a link?

Comment: Reload page. Works like a charm.

Comment: Can you create new question and ask me? :)

Comment: Yeah i saw :) Just i dont know how to stop it from opening a new tab now.

Comment: Also please check my post as the best answer?

Comment: We'll whatever it doesnt bother me so i guess. I'll give you the link when done.

Comment: I'm waiting for it ;)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584204/how-do-i-stop-my-search-bar-from-opening-a-new-tab