# How do i stop my search bar from opening a new tab?

Tags: php, html, search

How do i stop my search bar from opening a new tab? I dont see whats making it do that? Heres my php code. I've been having a couple issues with this search bar recently...

Heres my code (It is very very long...):

```
 <?php
    $xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
    $xmlDoc->load("links.xml");

    $x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

    //get the q parameter from URL
    $q=$_GET["q"];

    //lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
    if (strlen($q)>0)
    {
    $hint="";
    for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++)
      {
      $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title');
      $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');
      if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1)
        {
        //find a link matching the search text
        if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q))
          {
          if ($hint=="")
            {
            $hint="<a href='" . 
            $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
            "' target='_blank'>" . 
            $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
            }
          else
            {
            $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . 
            $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
            "' target='_blank'>" . 
            $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Set output to "No suggestions" if no hint were found
    // or to the correct values
    if ($hint=="")
      {
      $response="No suggestion";
      }
    else
      {
      $response=$hint;
      }

    //output the response
    echo $response;
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you expect `"' target='_blank'>" .` to do?

Comment: On the web page or on the code above

Answer (score 8):

you need to remove remove target='_blank'

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
            "' target='_blank'>" .
```

by this

```
$z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . 
            "'>" .
```

tag `target="_blank"` make opening link in new window